# Wireless data transmission between Seeeduino v.3 and Arduino using RF_2530a ver.11

Tags: arduino, relay

I'm sorry if this is a weird question. I have this project from my school. Here's my setup:

1. Seeeduino Stalker v3
2. UartSBee v.4
3. RF_2530 or known as CC2530 (maybe)
4. Arduino Duemilanove
5. 2-channel relay shield

[image]

So on the first image I have the RF2530 attached to my relay shield and also attached to my Arduino.

[image]

On my second image, the RF2530 is attached to the UartSBee.

And lastly I have my Seeeduino connected to the UartSBee by using jumper wire:

```
Seeeduino----------UartSBee

5v-----------------------VCC

TX-----------------------RX

RX-----------------------TX

GND---------------------GND

DTR----------------------DTR
```

My goal is, the Seeeduino will receive a GPIO pin from another device, for example if the Seeeduino receives pin 4 HIGH, the LED of RELAY1 will turn on, or if the Seeeduino receives pin 4 LOW, the LED of RELAY1 will turn off.

My problem is, if for example the Seeeduino receives pin 4 HIGH, the relay1 LED doesn't turn on.

Here's my code:

```
const int relay1 = 4;
const int relay2 = 5;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(57600);
  pinMode(relay1, INPUT);
  pinMode(relay2, INPUT);
}

void loop(){
  digitalRead(relay1);
  digitalRead(relay2);

  if(relay1 == 1) {
    Serial.println("#M9"); //relay1 HIGH,turn on relay 1 LED
  }
  if(relay1 == 0) {
    Serial.println("MA"); // relay1 LOW,turn off relay 1 LED
  }

  if(relay2 == 1) {
    Serial.println("#MB"); //relay2 HIGH,turn on relay 2 LED
  }
  if(relay2 == 0) {
    Serial.println("MC"); //relay2 LOW,turn off relay 2 LED
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Can someone point out what I'm missing? Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your if sentences are wrong. Change for this:

```
if(digitalRead(relay1) == 1) {
    Serial.println("#M9"); //relay1 HIGH,turn on relay 1 LED
  }
  if(digitalRead(relay1) == 0) {
    Serial.println("MA"); // relay1 LOW,turn off relay 1 LED
  }

  if(digitalRead(relay2) == 1) {
    Serial.println("#MB"); //relay2 HIGH,turn on relay 2 LED
  }
  if(digitalRead(relay2) == 0) {
    Serial.println("MC"); //relay2 LOW,turn off relay 2 LED
  }
```

In the first of your if senteces you are comparing 4==1, at the second 4==0 ...